# Правильно ли расставлены знаки?

Tags: синтаксис

Пусть во все времена на Руси растут богатыри такие, чтобы никто и никогда не смог бы побороть Россия и даже думать об этом не мог. 
Правильно ли я расставил знаки? Это из ЕГЭ. А еще интересно, какая основа во второй части?

Answer (score 1):

Знаки препинания расставлены правильно, это СПП с придаточным определительным.  Придаточное имеет  двойное значение "определение + цель", при этом используются пара указательное слово  ТАКОЙ + союз ЧТОБЫ.

Основа придаточного предложения: никто  не смог бы побороть и думать не мог. Здесь однородные   сказуемые, соединенные союзом И (поэтому нет запятой).

Сказуемые составные глагольные, вспомогательные глаголы НЕ СМОГ БЫ и  НЕ МОГ  с модальным значением.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

А) НИКТО И НИКОГДА - при разборе предложения надо указать роль союза И. Может быть, стоит считать его присоединительным союзом, который используется для образования  устойчивого сочетания подлежащего и обстоятельства? В любом случае, синтаксическая конструкция предложения нестандартная.

б) ПРИДАТОЧНЫЕ МЕРЫ И СТЕПЕНИ относятся к прилагательному или наречию (а не к существительному, как в нашем случае), что можно видеть по указательному слову: Он бежал ТАК быстро, чтобы успеть на поезд. Он выбрал ТАКУЮ трудную тему, чтобы никто усомнился в его знаниях.

Comment: Никогда - подлежащее?

Comment: У меня тоже предложенная грамматическая основа вызвала вопрос:  разве НИКОГДА входит в грамм.основу?

Comment: > Никогда - подлежащее?

Это с какого перепугу, позвольте поинтересоваться, "никогда" вдруг станет подлежащим?
"Никто" - подлежащее, "не смог бы побороть" и "думать не мог" - однородные сказуемые. С грамматической основой все понятно. Лично у меня больше вопросов вызывают лексические и грамматические ошибки.

Comment: Извините, ошибка, я даже об этом на подсознательном уровне вспомнила. Думаю, а откуда там у тебя однородные подлежащие-то взялись!

Comment: Что касается стиля, то, может быть, вот так будет лучше: "Пусть во все времена растут на Руси  такие богатыри, чтобы никто и никогда  не смог бы побороть Россию, да и подумать об этом  даже не смел".

Comment: На мой взгляд, со стилем все в порядке, а вот выражение "во все времена" обычно употребляется в сообщениях, повествующих о прошлом, разве нет? Частица "бы" попросту избыточна. Ну и глагол "растут" тоже не вполне уместен. Может, лучше сказать "рождаются"?

Comment: Надо бы весь текст иметь для правки, чтобы сказать по поводу "во все времена". Слово "рождаются" имеет более универсальный смысл и лучше подходит, "растут богатыри" - это какая-то детская тема. А по поводу частицы "БЫ" надо подумать: какой оттенок смысла она вносит в предложение?

Comment: > Надо бы весь текст иметь для правки, чтобы сказать по поводу "во все времена".

В имеющемся у нас отрывке имеется слово "пусть", отсылающее нас к желаемому будущему.

>А по поводу частицы "БЫ" надо подумать: какой оттенок смысла она вносит в предложение?

В данное предложение - оттенок желательности, я думаю. Но нуждается ли в оттенках сообщение, в котором желаемое посредством слов "никто" и "никогда" охарактеризовано с исчерпывающей полнотой?

Comment: Зачем править стиль текста, если это из ЕГЭ и нужно лишь расставить знаки препинания? А вот придаточное всё-таки местоимённо-определительное, а не определительное с оттенком цели: указат. мест.+ союз чтобы-показатель местоимённо-определительного придаточного. Для ЕГЭ это важно, хотя в этом случае не играет роли. И ошибка: ...не смог бы побороть РоссиИ (рифма такие-России)

Comment: Хотелось бы уточнить по поводу определительных и местоименно-определительных предложений. Я считала, что местоименно-определительными являются такие предложения:"Кто смел, тот уверен в себе.Я всё тот же, какой был.Не видим мы того, что видно ясно". А у нас указательное слово ТАКОЙ является определением, именно его содержание раскрывает придаточное предложение. НО такая трактовка соответствует Грамматике-80 - может быть, в школе другая методика?

Comment: И еще у меня вопрос к форуму по поводу "никто и никогда". Каким членом предложения является выражение  "и никогда", которое так тесно связано с местоимением "никто" ? А что если считать "никто и никогда" устойчивым сочетанием в роли подлежащего?

Comment: Я тоже считала всегда, что мест. ТАКОЙ подразумевает характеристику определительного предложения с доп.значением степени или цели,для мест.-определительного характерны мест. ТОТ,ВСЯКИЙ,ЛЮБОЙ,ВСЕ,ТЕ,ТО,МНОГИЕ ИЗ ТЕХ,т.е. они должны быть подлежащим в главном, а несколько раз уже такой ответ засчитывался как ошибка,так что я уже и не знаю. Может, их прокол в ответах,а может, что-то упростили.Я поэтому и против всяких изменений в теории, только научишь одному - кто-то возьмёт и поменяет.

Comment: Никто и никогда, конечно, связаны тесно, но так как они являются разными членами предложения,отвечая на разные вопросы, нет смысла считать выражение слитным в роли подлежащего, ведь может последовать вопрос "а почему не в роли обстоятельства?"Они просто усиливают отрицательный смысл друг друга. А "никто никогда никого"не обидит - тоже слитное сочетание?- Нет, это разные члены предложения с анафорическим повтором приставки.

Comment: Определительные придаточные присоединяются к главной части ТОЛЬКО союзными словами. А здесь скорее придаточное меры и степени с дополнительным значением цели.